# Style.DataTrigger on Border background

Tags: wpf, xml, styles, border, datatrigger

I have the border below. Why would the Foreground of my TextBlock work correctly but the Background of the border always stay the same (as if the IsDeleted property is always false)

```
<Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderBrush="Black" Background="#CBE2FF" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5" Padding="0" Margin="5">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDeleted}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#A00000"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
    <TextBlock Margin="5" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Text="Queue Details">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDeleted}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You have explicitely set the background value on the border. This has more priority than the trigger. Remove the `Background="#CBE2FF"` and take it into the style.

```
<Border.Style>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CBE2FF"/>
      ...
```

This will help.

Comment: perfect. i didn't know if i set it in the property it over-rode that. thanks